# OS upgrade `on-the-fly`

Tags: installation, server, automation, puppet

I wonder if there is a way how to install newer version of OS, let's say 14.04 (when it comes) on the second partition of my server disk from within running OS (e.g. Ubuntu 12.04), then change grub boot order and reboot to new system (reducing the server downtime)?

Scenario:

1st partition - Ubuntu 12.04 - happy and running
2nd partition - empty

new LTS comes

1st partition - Ubuntu 12.04 (server still running) - install 14.04 on second partition
2nd partition - installation in progress

reboot after installation

1st partition - old system (about to be wiped out)
2nd partition - server running on 14.04 now (down time reduced to one reboot)

Any ideas how this could be achieved? Is puppet capable of automation of this kind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably *could* do but before I get to that, consider the traditional approach:

1. Wait for out-of-hours. Few servers *need* to be active 24/7 and those that do usually have a failover system that allows you to upgrade one server at a time without *any* downtime. If it's not important enough to have an hour of planned downtime, you can schedule an upgrade.
2. Make a disk backup onto your second disk. But you already make these regularly, right?
3. Do your standard LTS-to-LTS upgrade. Fix anything that's broken and move on. The services on the server will remain active as long as they can (MySQL et al will restart themselves on upgrades but they usually come straight back up).

---

The only way to do what you're asking is with a virtual machine. You could try lightweight LXC or schroot methods but I think you'll probably want to go for VirtualBox if only because it's old and documented.

Install it, create a VM with near-physical, raw access to the disk, install Ubuntu and get everything set up. I will grant you, this gives you a lot of flexibility for getting things reconfigured if you need to change anything in the upgrade.

---

The other and only true high-availability approach is the hot-replacement/failover approach. Start a brand new server, install Ubuntu, get it configured, sync the data (ideally sharing it from a SAN over NFS between all servers so there's some atomic consistency) and get it up and running. Flick the switch and in a new microseconds, the new server takes the place of the old one.

A more modern approach to this is to just virtualise on all your metal so that even if you only have one physical host server, you could just create another VM for your new server and do a simple soft switch.

---

I think the first, traditional method gives you the most security without complicating an existing production setup with things like virtual machines (assuming they're not in place already).

Comment: Hi Oli, thanks for all your tips. I will definitely try out your idea with the VirtualBox, that sounds as most suitable for what we need!